# htaccess rewrite/modrewrite help!

Tags: html, .htaccess

I have the following url `http://puppetweb.ca/play/jokes.php?c=Get Well Soon` (Get Well Soon, can be any category name like Adult Jokes, Blah Blah, it will always be spaced though so `XXXX XXXX` format) and I want to change it so it is like `http://puppetweb.ca/play/Get-Well-Soon/` (or what ever the category name is)

I have

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule http://puppetweb.ca/(.*)/$ /jokes.php?c=$1
```

But it doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewriting `http://puppetweb.ca/play/Get-Well-Soon/` to `http://puppetweb.ca/play/jokes.php?c=Get Well Soon`. Is that what you want? If so, add this rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^play/(.*)/$ /play/jokes.php?c=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your regex is looking for a trailing / at the end of the line. Try this...

```
RewriteRule http://puppetweb.ca/(.*)/?$ /jokes.php?c=$1
```